# customize html table of pytest with docstring of the test

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I have a pytest test function as below.

```
def test_mytest():
    ''' this is my awesome test '''
    assert 1==1
```

I'd like to print this *test_mytest.docstring* in the html report as a column between test and duration columns.
I could gather that the *pytest_runtest_makereport()* pytest.mark.hookwrapper could help.
Is there any code snippets that I can use as a reference to make the modification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately the exact example is mention in the pytest-html user guide.
[https://pytest-html.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#modifying-the-results-table](https://pytest-html.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#enhancing-reports)
A mere copy paste of the example adds the docstring to the title